# How can I replace a "Request" class method for ASP.NET Core View class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to migrate few View classes into .NET Core from .NET and I am having an issue with the lack of "Request" class methods.

My specific code is as follows:

```
<form id="contactUs" method="post" action="@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)@Url.Action("ContactUsFormSubmit")" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

How can I replace the `Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)` part for .NET Core syntax?

Is there a better way of calling the authority part in .NET Core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Request` can now be found as `Request` in the Controller (from the base class) or at `@Context.Request` if you are in a MVC View.

<del>But there is no replacement</del>  for `Request.Url`  so you need to make it yourself: (see EDIT)

```
string.Concat(Request.Scheme, 
    "://", 
    Request.Host.ToUriComponent(), 
    Request.PathBase.ToUriComponent(), 
    Request.Path.ToUriComponent(),
    Request.QueryString.ToUriComponent())
```

But in your case it doesn't seems to be necessary. You could let the browser handle the relative path...

```
<form id="contactUs" method="post" action="@Url.Action("ContactUsFormSubmit")" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Or use MVC Core native way (using tag helpers):

```
<form asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="ContactUsFormSubmit" method="post">
```

**EDIT:** Actually there is a replacement for `Request.Url` :

Add: `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;`
Then call `Request.GetDisplayUrl();`... That will return `https://localhost/MyController/MyAction?Param1=blah`.

Comment: I'm honestly just migrating the project and not sure why they decided to do it this way. This is a stripped down web app that is used as a web form. So simple tag helpers also makes more sense to me but i'll ask to my manager about the purpose of getting the authority url. They use this form specifically in multiple medicine websites and the main page. Could there be any reason for getting the authority url? thanks

Comment: @KemalTezerDilsiz is like they wanted to point to absolute url's... But I dont know why they would want to do that...

Comment: I have this other piece of code in the same View class:
`<script>
    function loadjsfile(filename) {
        ...
    };
    if (jQuery == undefined) loadjsfile("@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js");
    loadjsfile("@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js");
    loadjsfile("@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js");
</script>`
Could it be possibly related? How could I replace this?

Comment: @KemalTezerDilsiz You are looking for `@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2‌​.min.js")`